# Request body is undefined when submitting Form Data object using supertest

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mocha.js, form-data, supertest

I have a web application in Vue which talks with a REST API written in NodeJS. In the web application, user can submit a file aside with it's information. The web passes this information to the backend using the REST API. The code in the web side:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("number", this.number);
formData.append("file", this.file);
// More fields inside the Form Data object

this.$http.post('http://localhost:8081/api/new',formData,{emulateJSON: true},{
    header:{ "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data" },
}).then(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 200) {
        this.handleClose();
    } else {
        console.log("Failed to submit new report");
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Failed to submit new report");
});
```

In the backend side, I have:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/new', function(request, response) {
  console.log("New Report");
  console.log(request.body);

  var info = {
    "number": request.body.number,
    // More fields
  };
  var file = request.files.file;

  // More Code
  
});
```

It works great but now I want to create tests for the REST API. I have the following code:

```
const chai     = require('chai');
const nock     = require('nock');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const request  = require('supertest');

run_new_report_test: function(server) {
    describe('Test: New report check', function() {
        it('should return status 200', function(done) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("number", "55555");
            // More fields
            request(server)
                .post('/api/new')
                .set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
                .attach(formData)
                .expect(200)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    expect(err).to.equal(null);
                    expect(res.body).to.be.an('object').that.is.not.empty;
                    expect(res.body.message).to.be.equal('success');
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
},
```

But when I run the test using `mocha`, I get:

```
New Report
undefined
```

For some reason `request.body` is `undefined`. I don't understand where the `FormData` fields are located in `request`. Why it works when I make a request from the web but not from the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `form-data`, you need to use `.field`(for req.body), and `.attach`(for file) methods. check the docs: https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests

also, you can mock file with buffer, you need to add some file info as well, try this:

```
describe('Test: New report check', function() {

    it('should return status 200', function(done) {

        const testFile = 'test file';

        request(server)
            .post('/api/new')
            // add each filed for req.body
            .field('number', '99999')
            // mock file
            .attach('file', Buffer.from(testFile, 'utf-8'), {

                // add file info accordingly
                filename: 'file.txt',
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                knownLength: testFile.length

            })
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                expect(err).to.equal(null);
                expect(res.body).to.be.an('object').that.is.not.empty;
                expect(res.body.message).to.be.equal('success');
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pass the data in params frontend side and you try to access in body row data in backend side that's why undefined.

try this

```
router.post('/new', function(request, response) {
console.log("New Report");
console.log(request.param);

var info = {
   "number": request.param.number,
   // More fields
};
var file = request.files.file;

 // More Code

});
```